# How to make this table responsive? Already tried many methods

Tags: html, css, html-table

https://codepen.io/NinjaInShade/pen/ExEEMJM

Basically, I don't want any data to wrap on new lines, and if the cells come together and cant squash any further, I want the table to start applying horizontal scroll.

I've tried many methods from stack overflow, but I can't seem to figure out what the problem is?

The table component simplified:

```html
<div class="container">
    <table>
        <tr class="header">
            <tr class="header"><th class="header-text" style="width: auto">ID</th><th class="header-text side-padding" style="width: 100%">Title</th><th class="header-text side-padding" style="width: auto">Category</th><th class="header-text side-padding" style="width: auto">Date Created</th><th class="header-text side-padding align-vertical" style="width: auto">Size</th><th class="header-text align-vertical" style="width: auto">Priority</th></tr>
        </tr>
            <tr class="data-row">
              <td class="data-text">#1</td>
              <td class="data-text side-padding">
                <div>
                  <p class="data-text">Qui dolorem sit corrupti....</p>
                  <span class="data-text-small">Updated on 02/08/2022</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="data-text side-padding">Maintenance</td>
              <td class="data-text side-padding">
                <div>
                  <p class="data-text">4th January, 2018</p>
                  <span class="data-text-small">7:31 pm</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="data-text side-padding align-vertical align-horizontal">
                <div class="size-tab">Small</div>
              </td>
              <td class="data-text align-vertical align-horizontal">
                <div class="priority-circle" style="background-color: var(--grey-                 darkest)"><span>5</span></div>
              </td>
          </tr>
              <tr class="data-row">
              <td class="data-text">#1</td>
              <td class="data-text side-padding">
                <div>
                  <p class="data-text">Qui dolorem sit corrupti....</p>
                  <span class="data-text-small">Updated on 02/08/2022</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="data-text side-padding">Maintenance</td>
              <td class="data-text side-padding">
                <div>
                  <p class="data-text">4th January, 2018</p>
                  <span class="data-text-small">7:31 pm</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="data-text side-padding align-vertical align-horizontal">
                <div class="size-tab">Small</div>
              </td>
              <td class="data-text align-vertical align-horizontal">
                <div class="priority-circle" style="background-color: var(--grey-                 darkest)"><span>5</span></div>
              </td>
          </tr>
              <tr class="data-row">
              <td class="data-text">#1</td>
              <td class="data-text side-padding">
                <div>
                  <p class="data-text">Qui dolorem sit corrupti....</p>
                  <span class="data-text-small">Updated on 02/08/2022</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="data-text side-padding">Maintenance</td>
              <td class="data-text side-padding">
                <div>
                  <p class="data-text">4th January, 2018</p>
                  <span class="data-text-small">7:31 pm</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="data-text side-padding align-vertical align-horizontal">
                <div class="size-tab">Small</div>
              </td>
              <td class="data-text align-vertical align-horizontal">
                <div class="priority-circle" style="background-color: var(--grey-                 darkest)"><span>5</span></div>
              </td>
          </tr>
              <tr class="data-row">
              <td class="data-text">#1</td>
              <td class="data-text side-padding">
                <div>
                  <p class="data-text">Qui dolorem sit corrupti....</p>
                  <span class="data-text-small">Updated on 02/08/2022</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="data-text side-padding">Maintenance</td>
              <td class="data-text side-padding">
                <div>
                  <p class="data-text">4th January, 2018</p>
                  <span class="data-text-small">7:31 pm</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="data-text side-padding align-vertical align-horizontal">
                <div class="size-tab">Small</div>
              </td>
              <td class="data-text align-vertical align-horizontal">
                <div class="priority-circle" style="background-color: var(--grey-                 darkest)"><span>5</span></div>
              </td>
          </tr>            <tr class="data-row">
              <td class="data-text">#1</td>
              <td class="data-text side-padding">
                <div>
                  <p class="data-text">Qui dolorem sit corrupti....</p>
                  <span class="data-text-small">Updated on 02/08/2022</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="data-text side-padding">Maintenance</td>
              <td class="data-text side-padding">
                <div>
                  <p class="data-text">4th January, 2018</p>
                  <span class="data-text-small">7:31 pm</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="data-text side-padding align-vertical align-horizontal">
                <div class="size-tab">Small</div>
              </td>
              <td class="data-text align-vertical align-horizontal">
                <div class="priority-circle" style="background-color: var(--grey-                 darkest)"><span>5</span></div>
              </td>
          </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

By the way, the "style: width auto/100%" are added by javascript incase I want to make a column behave like flex grow and take up the most room it can.

The CSS simplified:

```css
:root {
    font-size: 16px;

    --warning: #4081bf;
    --confirm: #709f60;
    --caution: #cabc42;
    --error: #bf4040;

    --primary: #041a2f;
    --primary-light: #062542;

    --blue: #0082ff;

    --white: #fff;
    --black: #000;

    --grey: #e5e5e5;
    --grey-light: #f7f7f7;
    --grey-dark: #999999;
    --grey-darkest: #666666;

    --fs-sm: 14px;
    --fs-sm-lh: 23px;

    --fs: 16px;
    --fs-lh: 27px;

    --fs-md: 19px;
    --fs-md-lh: 30px;

    --fs-lg: 36px;
    --fs-lg-lh: 48px;

    --border-radius: 8px;

    --padding-main: 75px;

    --padding-widget: 15px 20px;
    --padding-widget-x: 20px;
    --padding-widget-y: 15px;
}
   

table {
        table-layout: fixed;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        white-space: nowrap;
        width: 100%;
    }

    table .side-padding {
        padding-left: 40px;
        padding-right: 40px;
    }

    .container {
        border-radius: var(--border-radius) var(--border-radius) 0 0;
        overflow-x: auto;
    }

    table th {
        padding-top: 23px;
        padding-bottom: 23px;
    }

    table td {
        vertical-align: top;
        padding: 31px 0;
    }

    table th:first-child, table td:first-child {
        padding-left: 32px;
    }

    table th:last-child, table td:last-child {
        padding-right: 32px;
    }

    .header {
        background-color: var(--warning);
        border: 1px solid var(--warning);
    }

    .data-row {
        background-color: var(--white);
        border: 1px solid var(--grey);
        border-top: none;
    }

    table .align-vertical {
        text-align: center;
    }

    table align-horizontal {
       vertical-align: middle;
    }

    table .data-text {
        font-size: var(--fs);
        line-height: var(--fs-lh);
        color: var(--black);
        white-space: nowrap;
        font-weight: 500;
    }

    table .data-text-small {
        font-size: var(--fs-sm);
        line-height: var(--fs-sm-lh);
        color: var(--grey-darkest);
        white-space: nowrap;
        font-weight: 500;
    }

    .header-text {
        font-size: var(--fs);
        line-height: var(--fs);
        color: var(--white);
        font-weight: 600;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-align: left;
    }

.priority-circle {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 34px;
    width: 34px;
}

.priority-circle span {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: var(--fs-sm);
    line-height: var(--fs-sm);
    color: var(--white);
    font-weight: 700;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}

.size-tab {
    margin: auto;
    display: inline;
    background-color: var(--warning);
    font-size: var(--fs-sm);
    line-height: var(--fs-sm);
    color: var(--white);
    font-weight: 700;
    border-radius: 18px;
    padding: 8px 16px;
}
```

I just added:

```css
.table-container {
width: 100%;
overflow: auto;
}

.table {
...
table-layout: fixed;
width: 100%;
}
```

And I got this?
[image]

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: What do you mean "I don't want any data to wrap on new lines"?

Comment: I mean the text sorry. And the strings will be of somewhat uniform lengths

Comment: Give every td a fixed width, then you get a scrollbar.

Comment: This isn't really an option as im using svelte and right now I can't add "dynamic styles" if I return HTML, which is what I'm doing for every row when the table is rendered

Comment: Remove the several instances of `white-space: nowrap`.

Comment: you should insert `span` in `p` because `p` has `display block` or add css rule for `p { display: inline-block; }` and remove `width: 100%` for `table`.